# Converting Rspec mocks to Mocha for testing active-model-serializers

Tags: testing, rspec, mocking, active-model-serializers

I'm using Benedikt Diecke's post on custom rspec example groups to test active model serializers but having trouble converting this to use mocha instead of rspec mocks.

http://benediktdeicke.com/2013/01/custom-rspec-example-groups/

The example includes a generic method to mock the model class that will be serialized, it uses rspec mocks - how can I convert this to use mocha?

```
let(:resource) do
    double(resource_name, attributes).tap do |double|
        double.stub(:read_attribute_for_serialization) { |name| attributes[name] }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't see that there's much to be gained using a mock there. I'd return a real instance from the resource factory method, I.e. in the custom example group don't define let(:attributes) at all and just define

```
let(:resource) do
  {}
end
```

and then your serializer spec would look like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UserSerializer do
  let(:resource){ FactoryGirl.build(:resource_name) }

  it { should have_key(:name) }
  it { should have_key(:email) }
  it { should have_key(:created_at) }
  it { should have_key(:updated_at) }
end
```